# rails 3 additional parameter constraint in resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a resource route

```
resources :favorites
```

But I w'd like to have a request as

```
/favorites?sort_by=name
/favorites?sort_by=date
/favorites?sort_by=number
```

How can I limit a using only **name, date, number words** in request?

I have tried

```
resources :favorites, :constraints => {:sort_by => /name|date|number/}
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i used `/(name)|(date)|(number)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route constraint doesn't tested against query strings.

Create custom route on sort_by, and make it part of the route. Or constraint it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb place the following code

```
resources :favorites do
 member do
   get :sort_by, constraints: {id: /name|date|number/}
 end
end
```

it will generate

```
sort_by_favorite GET    /favorites/:id/sort_by(.:format)                  favorites#sort_by {:id=>/name|date|number/}
```

in "/favorites/:id/sort_by" URL, in place of :id you can pass 'name' or 'date' or 'number'. But I guess, it is not that you want.

So, if you want the following URLS

```
/favorites?sort_by=name
/favorites?sort_by=date
/favorites?sort_by=number
```

Then you have to write some condition in the index action of the Favorites controller.

```
def index
 if ['name', 'date', 'number'].include?(params['sort_by'])
  # your code goes here
 else
  # redirect to some where with error message
 end
end
```

Hope it will work for you :)